# Evaluation of integral of $x(x(1-x)^3)^{1/4}$ from $0$ to $1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been struggling with the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1} x \sqrt[4]{x(1-x)^3}dx
$$

I have tried to use different substitutions/ split the 4th root into double square roots and I can see it has some sort of symmetry to it but to no avail.

Wolfram alpha gives a rather complicated solution, but I was wondering if there was a clean way of solving this.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $\frac{x}{1-x}=t^4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's
$$\int_0^1 x^{5/4}(1-x)^{3/4}\,dx=B(9/4,7/4)$$
where $B(a,b)$ denotes the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
It equals
$$\frac{\Gamma(9/4)\Gamma(7/4)}{\Gamma(4)}=\frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{4}
\frac{3}{4}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)}{3!}.$$
By Euler's reflection formula,
$$\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)=\frac\pi{\sin\pi/4}=\pi\sqrt2.$$
Then
$$\int_0^1 x^{5/4}(1-x)^{3/4}\,dx=\frac{5}{128}\sqrt2\,\pi.$$

Comment: Thanks for this! Didn't think of the Beta function.